# Array summation based on length provided by user

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sum an array where array length will be provided by user. I have done it but execution time is high then required. What is an efficient way to do it. my code

```
function summation(){
 var p = prompt("Number Only","");
 var arr = [] ;
 var sum = 0 ;
 for (var i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    arr.push(parseInt(prompt("Number Only","")));
 };


 for (var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
 };
 document.write(sum);
}


(function(){
 summation();
})();
```

Comment: its taking user input

Comment: What does "execution time is high then required" mean? There's nothing in this code that would take any more than a couple of milliseconds even on the slowest computer.

Comment: @EdHeal See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

Comment: @juhana... well... `var i = 0; i < p; i++` logically

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ??? it asks for user input at every iteration. It wouldn't be noticeably slow no matter how many times it loops.

Comment: I was trying to solve a problem, where execution time is necessary @Juhana

Comment: @Juhana whatever he does inside the `for` which is clearly a nonsense... iterating over N can take N time.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan How is it nonsense? He's asking for user input in a prompt and pushing it to an array. The prompt pauses execution. There's no way anyone can notice a delay between the prompts (unless one is enforced by the browser).

Comment: Can anyone please help me to find an efficient way, i am still at the learning state

Comment: what kind of input are you expecting ? terabytes of data ?

Comment: How long does it take. How long do you want it to take?

Comment: @Amir You could get the whole array at once, ask user to give the values separated by comma, and use `split` method to create an array in the code.

Comment: @LyesBEN 
1≤N≤1000 
0≤A[i]≤1000

Comment: @bhspencer it takes 0.09 s and have to do it in 0.01

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the execution time is important? As Juhana said, entering values takes a long time compared to the calculation time.

Comment: I was trying to solve a problem where execution time is important @Teemu

Comment: @Amir How are you measuring the amount of time your code takes to run. Exactly where do you start the timer and where do you stop it?

Comment: online editor of Hacker Rank where i am trying to submit my code @bhspencer

Comment: @Amir presumably promoting for user input is not part of the function you are measuring execution time for. Exactly what code are you measuring execution time for?

Comment: execution time depends on the test cases in Hacker Rank, how much time is taking to run for code for a given input and if input in the range of 1≤N≤1000 
0≤A[i]≤1000

Answer (score 0):

Why to use an array when you don't need an array?

```
function summation(){
 var p = prompt("Number Only","");
 var sum=0;
 for(var i=0;i<p;i++){
   sum+=parseInt(prompt("Number Only", ""));
 }
 document.write(sum);
}
```

Comment: I have to push inputs in an array then have to find summation. I tried it earlier

Answer (score 0):

This solution features an infinite loop with break, a prompt with control, a continuing input and a type checking for numbers.

The first imput for the array size is not more necessary, because of the possibillity of immediately ending with cancel or empty input.

```js
function summation() {
    var arr = [],
        sum = 0,
        v;            
    while (true) {
        v = prompt("Number Only (Press [Cancel] for end input)", "");
        if (!v) {
            break;
        }
        v = parseInt(v, 10);
        if (isFinite(v)) {
            arr.push(v);
            sum += v;
        }
    }
    document.write('Array: ' + arr + '<br>');
    document.write('Sum: ' + sum + '<br>');
}
summation();
```